# Python - Do not click if statement is true

Tags: python, selenium, click

I have a table with x rows and 4 columns. My code clicks on every link in the table.

```
+----------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+
|    NR    |    Name     |     Assignee    |    Status    |
+----------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+
|    1     |     ABC     |        ME       |     DONE     |
|    2     |     DEF     |        ME       |    In Work   |
|    3     |     GHI     |       PAUL      |     DONE     |
+----------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

*Table is just for better explanation.

Now I want that my code doesn´t click on the link when Status is DONE!

This is my Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

total_tickets = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='ghx-issues-in-epic-table']/tbody/tr")
    # Click throug all Tickets
    for j in range(0,len(total_tickets)):
        ticket = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='ghx-issues-in-epic-table']/tbody/tr/td[2]/a")
        status = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ghx-issues-in-epic-table']/tbody/tr/td[5]/span").text
        if status == "DONE":
            for k in range(0,len(total_tickets)):
                ticket_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ghx-issues-in-epic-table']/tbody/tr/td[2]/a").text
                print ticket_name,"is allready done !"
        else:
            ticket[j].click()
            print driver.title
```

Here is one part of the HTML Table of the Website:

```
<table id="ghx-issues-in-epic-table" class="ghx-issuetable " data-rendered="1513339726797">
    <tbody>
        <tr data-issuekey="1" class="issuerow">
            <td class="nav ghx-minimal ghx-alt"></td>
            <td class="nav ghx-minimal">
                <a href="/browse/1">1</a>
            </td>
            <td class="nav ghx-summary">
                ABC
            </td>
            <td class="assignee">
                ME
            </td>
            <td class="nav status">
                <span class="status">
                    DONE
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I do not get an error. The output is that is says 4 times that the first link is DONE and then it stops.

I hope i could explain what i want and everything is clear.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Isnt the Xpath meant to be `/tbody/tr/td[5]/span` in the Status variable?

Comment: yes .. just forgot it to change it for this example .. in my code it have the correct xpath (copied it from the control box)

Comment: What happens if you print out the `status` variable? does it actually contain "DONE"?

Comment: status possibilities are: DONE / In Work / In Review / Testing ... and if i add `print status` it prints DONE or In Work or In Review or Testing

Comment: In your code you have status = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ghx-issues-in-epic-table']/tbody/tr/td[5]/span").text hardcoded you should make it dynamic or it will look always at the first element, so it find for 4 times "DONE"

Comment: @Carlo1585  don´t really knew how to change the code that it is dynamic .. hope you can help me or at least send a link to a documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

XPATH can do it for you:

```
all_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '//table//td[contains(@class, "status")]/span[not(contains(text(), "DONE"))]/../../td/a'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the tickets with **`Status != DONE`** you can use the following code block :

```
all_status = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='ghx-issues-in-epic-table']/tbody/tr//td[@class='nav status']/span[@class='status']")
for status in all_status :
    if ("DONE" not in status.get_attribute("innerHTML")) :
    status.find_element_by_xpath("//self/preceding::td[@class='nav ghx-minimal']/a").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @diem_L someone else made some example but I would give a different advice... The element are in a table and the xpath in your example is:

```
status = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ghx-issues-in-epic-table']/tbody/tr/td[5]/span").text
```

if the other column have similar xpath but change just the row probably they are:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ghx-issues-in-epic-table']/tbody/tr/td[5]/span").text
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ghx-issues-in-epic-table']/tbody/tr/td[6]/span").text
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ghx-issues-in-epic-table']/tbody/tr/td[7]/span").text
```

if you see change just the number (verify it); if this is the case you can create a variable and do a cycle.
Example:

```
l=len(LINE) #how many line you have in your table
i=0
while i<l:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ghx-issues-in-epic-table']/tbody/tr/td["+str(i)+"]/span").text #in this case if you see instead than the number 5 I put the variable str(i) that increment in each line, if your table start from number 5 and not 0 instead that i you could have put str(5+i)
    i+=1
```

I hope my example can be helpful.